# python program is super slow, and I can't find out why

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I'm writing a multi-layer perceptron from scratch and I think it's way slower than it should be. the culprit seems to be my `compute_gradients`-function, which according to my investigation answers for most of the execution time. It looks like this:

```
def compute_gradients(X, Y, S1, H, P, W1, W2, lamb):
    # Y must be one-hot
    # Y and P must be (10, n)
    # X and H must be (3072, n)
    # P is the softmax layer
    if not (Y.shape[0] == 10 and P.shape[0] == 10 and Y.shape == P.shape):
        raise ValueError("Y and P must have shape (10, k). Y: {}, P: {}".format(Y.shape, P.shape))
    if not X.shape[0] == n_input:
        raise ValueError("X must have shape ({}, k), has {}".format(n_input, X.shape))
    if not H.shape[0] == n_hidden:
        raise ValueError("H must have shape ({}, k)".format(n_hidden))
    grad_W1 = np.zeros([n_hidden, n_input])
    grad_W2 = np.zeros([10, n_hidden])
    grad_b1 = np.zeros([n_hidden, 1])
    grad_b2 = np.zeros([10, 1])


    X, Y, H, P = X.T, Y.T, H.T, P.T
    for x, y, s1, h, p in zip(X, Y, S1, H, P):
        h = np.reshape(h, [1, n_hidden])
        y = np.reshape(y, [10, 1])
        p = np.reshape(p, [10, 1])

        # Second layer
        g = -(y-p).T
        grad_b2 += g.T
        grad_W2 += np.matmul(g.T, h)
        # First layer
        g = np.matmul(g, W2)
        ind = np.zeros(h.shape[1])
        for i, val in enumerate(s1):
            if val > 0:
                ind[i] = 1
        diag = np.diag(ind)

        g = np.matmul(g, diag)

        grad_b1 += g.T
        grad_W1 += np.matmul(g.T, np.reshape(x, [1, n_input]))
    # Divide by batch size
    grad_b1 /= X.shape[0]
    grad_b2 /= X.shape[0]
    grad_W1 /= X.shape[0]
    grad_W2 /= X.shape[0]
    # Add regularization term
    grad_W1 += 2*lamb*W1
    grad_W2 += 2*lamb*W2
    return grad_W1, grad_W2, grad_b1, grad_b2
```

If `X, Y, H, P` are all 10 rows long (n=10), the computations take about 1 second. This is way too much compared to my friends who are doing the same task. But I can't see any obvious inefficiencies in my code. What can I do to speed the computations up?

EDIT: Input data is the CIFAR dataset. Load it like this:

```
def one_hot(Y):
    # assume Y = [1, 4, 9, 0, ...]
    result = [None]*len(Y)
    for i, cls in enumerate(Y):
        onehot = {
            0: lambda: [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            1: lambda: [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            2: lambda: [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            3: lambda: [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            4: lambda: [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
            5: lambda: [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
            6: lambda: [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
            7: lambda: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
            8: lambda: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
            9: lambda: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        }[cls]()
        result[i] = onehot

    result = np.array(result).T
    return result

def unpickle(file):
    import pickle
    with open(file, "rb") as fo:
        d = pickle.load(fo, encoding="bytes")
    return d

names = ["data_batch_1", 
         "data_batch_2", 
         "data_batch_3", 
         "data_batch_4", 
         "data_batch_5",
        ]


# All data sets

dataset_large = {"data": np.zeros([0, 3072]), "labels": np.array([])}
validation_large = {}

## All data batches

for name in names[0:4]:
    raw = unpickle(os.path.join(path, name))
    dataset_large["data"] = np.append(dataset_large["data"], raw[b"data"], axis = 0)
    dataset_large["labels"] = np.append(dataset_large["labels"], raw[b"labels"], axis = 0)
raw = unpickle(os.path.join(path, names[4]))
dataset_large["data"] = np.append(dataset_large["data"], raw[b"data"][0: -1000], axis = 0)
dataset_large["labels"] = np.append(dataset_large["labels"], raw[b"labels"][0: -1000], axis = 0)
validation_large["data"] = raw[b"data"][-1000: ]
validation_large["labels"] = raw[b"labels"][-1000: ]

# Make one-hot
dataset_large["labels"] = one_hot(dataset_large["labels"]).T
validation_large["labels"] = one_hot(validation_large["labels"]).T

# Normalize
dataset_large["data"] = dataset_large["data"]/255
validation_large["data"] = validation_large["data"]/255
```

the dataset can be found at https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-100-python.tar.gz . Then run like:

```
def evaluate_classifier(X, W1, W2, b1, b2):
    if not X.shape[0] == n_input:
        ValueError("Wrong shape of X: {}".format(X.shape))
    if not len(X.shape) == 2:
        ValueError("Wrong shape of X: {}".format(X.shape))
    if not W1.shape == (n_hidden, n_input):
        raise ValueError("Wrong shape of W1: {}".format(W1.shape))
    if not b1.shape == (n_hidden, 1):
        raise ValueError("Wrong shape of b1: {}".format(b1.shape))
    if not W2.shape == (10, n_hidden):
        raise ValueError("Wrong shape of W2: {}".format(W2.shape))
    if not b2.shape == (10, 1):
        raise ValueError("Wrong shape of b2: {}".format(b2.shape))

    s1, h = layer_1(X, W1, b1)

    p = layer_2(h, W2, b2)

    return s1, h, p

W1 = np.random.normal(0, 0.01, [n_hidden, n_input])
W2 = np.random.normal(0, 0.01, [10, n_hidden])
b1 = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, [n_hidden, 1])
b2 = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, [10, 1])

X = dataset_large["data"][0:10]
Y = dataset_large["labels"][0:10]
S1, H, P = evaluate_classifier(X, W1, W2, b1, b2)
lamb = 0
compute_gradients(X, Y, S1, H, P, W1, W2, lamb)
```

Comment: I believe this is question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @GSazheniuk It would be appropriate for Code Review, but it's [not necessarily off-topic here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286557/2615940).

Comment: First, are you sure your `compute_gradients` is taking much longer for each call, as opposed to being called a lot more often? (Because either way, `compute_gradients` would account for most of your execution time.)

Comment: Some fictitious data to input into your function would be nice. If you have a powerful enough gpu tensorflow May be an option. Or try to eliminate that for loop

Comment: I'm sure of that, @abarnert

Comment: @skrrgwasme That's something good to know, thank you!

Comment: @DJK, I've tried to make it as easy as possible to run the code with some data, see my edit.

Comment: Can you tell me the shape for `g` after executing `g = np.matmul(g, W2)`, and the shape of `diag` before executing `diag = np.diag(ind)`? I am thinking you probably don't need so many `matmul`s.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar
1. `(1, 3072)`
2. `diag` doesn't exist before executing `np.diag(ind)`.

Comment: One inner loop could be replaced with `ind=(val>0).astype(float)`.

Comment: What languages are your faster friends using?

Comment: @Sahand Sorry, I meant shape of `ind`. If it is `(1, 3072)` and then if you are converting it to `(3072, 3072)` and then you are multiplying `g` with `diag` to get `(1,3072)`, you might as well achieve the same by doing `np.dot(g, ind)`. Check for correctness though. Check whether if you can eliminate other `np.matmul`s too.

Comment: @hpaulj they are using python, too.